# MYSQL find INT in string

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column MEDIUMTEXT that contains values that come from a goup_concat, in the form of INT,INT,INT . We can call it Concatenated_IDs

The length of the string can be of 1 int or more.

I need to break it down into original values somehow to be able to do something such as

```
SELECT
  table_country.name
FROM
  table_country 
WHERE
  table_country.country_id IN (
   SELECT
     Concatenated_IDs
   FROM
     table_targeted_countries 
   WHERE
     table_targeted_countries.email LIKE "%gmail.com")
```

and get the country names that users registered with a gmail address target.

I have considered exploding the mediumtext into INT, creating one row for each int, sort of like a reverse concat, but I am guessing it would take a large procedure

edit:reformulated question name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably normalize that table, so those concated ids are stored in a separate table, one id per record. But in the mean time, you can use mysql's `find_in_set()` function:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(table_country.country_id, Concatenated_IDs) > 0
```

Relevant docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Comment: Thank you, find_in_set solved my problem.
table will be normalised some time in the future, it's in a long queue

Comment: LOCATE() would also work if you prefix and suffix all strings with ','.  e.g. `LOCATE(CONCAT(',', id_to_find, ','), CONCAT(',',Concatenated_IDs,','))`.  FIND_IN_SET() is made for this however.